DML on Sobject List
I have a scenario where I need to reduce DML calls. I'm performing DML on two objects that have a lookup relationship. I'm currently collecting the records in a list of SObjects and then performing the DML operations.
I've tested different scenarios and confirmed functionality remains intact. However, I'd like to confirm with experts - is it considered good practice to use a single list of SObjects(List)?

This feels like treating the symptom instead of the disease to me. Hard to tell what's going on without seeing any code, but are you sure that you don't have any DML inside of loops? I personally think that DML on a List<SObject> makes logs harder to read and things harder to debug. There's also the consideration that you need to avoid interleaving different SObject types in the list (otherwise you'd be liable to run into a "more than 10 chunks" error.

It depends on the circumstances, but the answer in general is "yes". When possible, you should do this, because a DML statement counts as one DML statement for the Governor Limits, even if multiple types of sObjects are involved. However, make sure you read about Things You Should Know about Data in Apex. Notably, you can't use more than 10 discrete sObject types in the list, the list should be sorted because every time you transistion between one sObject type and another counts against this limit of 10, and the list is batched into groups of 200 records, where each batch also count against this limit of 10, so the total maximum number of records you can affect in a single statement is limited to 2,000 per statement when used in this manner.
